# How to retrieve the values from previous jsp page to result page?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I am creating a quiz application. Here, there are 5 jsp pages with 5 different quizes. If I use 1 jsp page and result page, it is working fine..i.e; It is redirecting from QuizPage5.jsp and show the result in ResultPage.jsp.
I need to show all the results from QuizPage1.jsp, QuizPage2.jsp, QuizPage3.jsp, QuizPage4.jsp and QuizPage5.jsp to ResultPage.jsp.

I used

in jsp1 to pass value.

```
<form action="">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="hidden">
<input type="submit" value="submit"></form>
```

in jsp2 to get value

```
String value=request.getParameter("hidden");
```

But, I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Here is my code..

QuizPage1.jsp

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
            <script language="JavaScript">  

            function check()  
               {  
                   var radio_choice = false;  
                   for (counter = 0; counter < myform.grp.length; counter++)  
                    {  
                        if (myform.grp[counter].checked)  
                        radio_choice = true;  
                    }  
                        if (!radio_choice)  
                         {  
                            alert("Please select one.")  
                            return (false);  
                         }  
                         return(true);  
                     }  
</script>  
    </head>  
   <body> 
        <h3>Quiz No.1</h3>

        Q1.Which one of the following is the Capital of India?<br><br>  
        <form action="QuizPage2.jsp" method="post" name="myform" onsubmit="return check();">  
            <input type="radio" name="grp" value="New Delhi" >New Delhi<br>  
             <input type="radio" name="grp" value="Kolkata" >Kolkata<br>  
                 <input type="radio" name="grp" value="Chennai" >Chennai<br>  
                     <input type="radio" name="grp" value="Mumbai" >Mumbai<br>  
                     <br><br><input type="submit" value="Next Question"> 
                     <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="grp">
                     <input type="submit" value ="Back" onclick="window.history.back();"/> 

        </form>  
      </body>



</html>
```

QuizPage2.jsp

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
            <script language="JavaScript">  

            function check()  
               {  
                   var radio_choice = false;  
                   for (counter = 0; counter < myform2.grp2.length; counter++)  
                    {  
                        if (myform2.grp2[counter].checked)  
                        radio_choice = true;  
                    }  
                        if (!radio_choice)  
                         {  
                            alert("Please select any one Answer");  
                            return (false);  
                         }  
                         return(true);  
                     }  
</script>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <h3>Quiz No.2</h3>

        Q2. Where is Chennai Located?<br><br>  
        <form action="QuizPage3.jsp"method="post" name="myform2" onsubmit="return check();">  
            <input type="radio" name="grp2" value="Karnataka" >Karnataka<br>  
             <input type="radio" name="grp2" value="Tamilnadu" >Tamilnadu<br>  
                 <input type="radio" name="grp2" value="Andhra Pradesh" >Andhra Pradesh<br>  
                     <input type="radio" name="grp2" value="Maharashtra" >Maharashtra<br>  
                     <br><br><input type="submit" value="Next Question">  
                      <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="grp2">
                     <input type="submit" value ="Back" onclick="window.history.back();"/> 


        </form>  
        <%
            String s1=request.getParameter("grp");
         %>
      </body>  
</html>
```

QuizPage3.jsp

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
            <script language="JavaScript">  

            function check()  
               {  
                   var radio_choice = false;  
                   for (counter = 0; counter < myform3.grp3.length; counter++)  
                    {  
                        if (myform3.grp3[counter].checked)  
                        radio_choice = true;  
                    }  
                        if (!radio_choice)  
                         {  
                            alert("Please select any one Answer");  
                            return (false);  
                         }  
                         return(true);  
                     }  
</script>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <h3>Quiz No.3</h3>
        Q3. What is the largest state in the USA<br><br>  
        <form action="QuizPage4.jsp"method="post" name="myform" onsubmit="return check();">  
            <input type="radio" name="grp3" value="New York" >New York<br>  
             <input type="radio" name="grp3" value="Alaska" >Alaska<br>  
                 <input type="radio" name="grp3" value="California" >California<br>  
                     <input type="radio" name="grp3" value="Melbourne" >Melbourne<br>  
                     <br><br><input type="submit" value="Next Question">  
                     <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="grp3">
                     <input type="submit" value ="Back" onclick="window.history.back();"/> 

        </form>  
        <%
            String s2=request.getParameter("grp2");
         %>
      </body>  
</html>
```

QuizPage4.jsp

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
            <script language="JavaScript">  

            function check()  
               {  
                   var radio_choice = false;  
                   for (counter = 0; counter < myform4.grp4.length; counter++)  
                    {  
                        if (myform4.grp4[counter].checked)  
                        radio_choice = true;  
                    }  
                        if (!radio_choice)  
                         {  
                            alert("Please select any one Answer");  
                            return (false);  
                         }  
                         return(true);  
                     }  
</script>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <h3>Quiz No.4</h3>
        Q4. The famous Dilwara Temples are situated in<br><br>  
        <form action="QuizPage5.jsp"method="post" name="myform" onsubmit="return check();">  
            <input type="radio" name="grp4" value="Uttar Pradesh" >Uttar Pradesh<br>  
             <input type="radio" name="grp4" value="Maharashtra" >Maharashtra<br>  
                 <input type="radio" name="grp4" value="Andhra Pradesh" >Andhra Pradesh<br>  
                     <input type="radio" name="grp4" value="Rajasthan" >Rajasthan<br>  
                     <br><br><input type="submit" value="Next Question"> 
                     <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="grp4">
                     <input type="submit" value ="Back" onclick="window.history.back();"/> 

        </form> 
        <%
            String s3=request.getParameter("grp3");
         %>
      </body>  
</html>
```

QuizPage5.jsp

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
            <script language="JavaScript">  

            function check()  
               {  
                   var radio_choice = false;  
                   for (counter = 0; counter < myform5.grp5.length; counter++)  
                    {  
                        if (myform5.grp5[counter].checked)  
                        radio_choice = true;  
                    }  
                        if (!radio_choice)  
                         {  
                            alert("Please select any one Answer");  
                            return (false);  
                         }  
                         return(true);  
                     }  
</script>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <h3>Quiz No.5</h3>
        Q5. The Indian Institute of Science is located at<br><br>  
        <form action="ResultPage.jsp"method="post" name="myform" onsubmit="return check();">  
            <input type="radio" name="grp5" value="Chennai" >Chennai<br>  
             <input type="radio" name="grp5" value="Bangalore" >Bangalore<br>  
                 <input type="radio" name="grp5" value="Mumbai" >Mumbai<br>  
                     <input type="radio" name="grp5" value="Hyderabad" >Hyderabad<br>  
                     <br><br><input type="submit" value="Show Result"> 
                     <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="grp5"/>


        </form> 
        <%
            String s4=request.getParameter("grp4");
         %>
      </body>  
</html>
```

ResultPage.jsp

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
        <title>Quiz Result</title>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
          <%  
     String answer="New Delhi";  
     String s1=request.getParameter("grp");  
     if(s1.equals(answer))  
         {  
        out.println("Correct Answer");  
         }  
     else  
         {out.println("Wrong Answer! The Correct Answer is :"+answer);  
     }  
    %> 
    <%  
     String answer2="Tamilnadu";  
     String s2=request.getParameter("grp2");  
     if(s2.equals(answer2))  
         {  
        out.println("Correct Answer");  
         }  
     else  
         {out.println("Wrong Answer! The Correct Answer is :"+answer2);  
     }  
    %> 
    <%  
     String answer3="Alaska";  
     String s3=request.getParameter("grp3");  
     if(s3.equals(answer3))  
         {  
        out.println("Correct Answer");  
         }  
     else  
         {out.println("Wrong Answer! The Correct Answer is :"+answer3);  
     }  
    %> 
    <%  
     String answer4="Rajasthan";  
     String s4=request.getParameter("grp4");  
     if(s4.equals(answer4))  
         {  
        out.println("Correct Answer");  
         }  
     else  
         {out.println("Wrong Answer! The Correct Answer is :"+answer4);  
     }  
    %> 
        <%  
         String answer5="Bangalore";  
         String s5=request.getParameter("grp5");  
         if(s5.equals(answer5))  
             {  
            out.println("Correct Answer");  
             }  
         else  
             {out.println("Wrong Answer! The Correct Answer is :"+answer5);  
         }  
        %> 


    </body> 
</html>
```

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You seriously have 5 separate pages with identical code where only the textual content differs? You need to have ONE page with an array of questions...

Comment: I used in this way..Is there any solution?

Comment: @Dinesh Kumar Solution is to implement it as `mplungjan` said above.

Comment: I am new to jsp. So I know this way only..If you can, help me out of this

Comment: Hi, I checked your code , for page QuizPage1 and QuizPage2 , its working fine. No error is coming.

Comment: In ResultPage only, I am getting org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want data that can be access across multiple pages, consider using the session to store data.  For example, if page1.jsp submits a form parameter, "page1Result" to page2.jsp, then in page2.jsp, do the following:

```
String page1Result = request.getParameter("page1Result");
request.getSession().setAttribute("page1Result", page1Result);
```

Then at some point down the road (say on page 5), you can access the page1 value as follows:

```
String page1Value = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("page1Result);
```

================================================================================
So applying this to your code:

In page2 jsp, change the scriptlet at the end of the file to:

```
    <%
     String s1=request.getParameter("grp");
     request.getSession().setAttribute("s1", s1);
     %>
```

And in page 3 JSP, change the script let to:

```
    <%
     String s2=request.getParameter("grp2");
     request.getSession().setAttribute("s2", s2);
     %>
```

And so on.

And finally on ResultPage.jsp (just showing example one line for answer 2)

```
out.println("Wrong Answer! The Correct Answer for question 2 is :"+session.getAttribute("s2"));
```

Comment: It is showing cannot find symbol error on each jsp page on putAttribute

Comment: sorry, that should be "setAttribute"

Comment: Ya right..Thank you..and one more thing. Is it possible to show the consolidated result in ResultPage.jsp by saying. Out of 5, 2 is right and 3 is wrong. like that ?

Comment: Yes it is.  Given that all 5 of the user answers are in the session (and thus accessible from your results page), you can write a few lines of code that count how many of the user answers match the expected answers.

Answer (score 0):

on jsp1

```
String passThis = "pass this value";
request.setAttribute("param1",passThis);
```

dispatch to jsp 2

in jsp2

```
String getParam = request.getAttribute("param1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch questions by `JavaScript` and submit everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

I have not detailed look on the code. But the question requires a multiple request paradigm. But result.jsp though takes all the answer from request object. Whereas it should be the session object. And answer to each question should be stored in session. So it is accessible and doesn't gets descoped.