# How to display the result in last page by collecting the results from previous jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating a quiz application. Here, there are 5 jsp pages with 5 different quizes.  I need to show all the results from QuizPage1.jsp, QuizPage2.jsp, QuizPage3.jsp, QuizPage4.jsp and QuizPage5.jsp to ResultPage.jsp.

I used session to get the answers from all jsp page. But, I need to display the result in last page as..

Question 1: Wrong Answer - Correct answer is .......
Question 2: Wrong Answer - Correct answer is .......
Question 3: Wrong Answer - Correct answer is .......
Question 4: Wrong Answer - Correct answer is .......
Question 5: Wrong Answer - Correct answer is .......

I used this scriplet in every jsp page by changing parameter..

```
     <%
     String s1=request.getParameter("grp");
     request.getSession().setAttribute("s1", s1);
     %>
```

Is there any solution?

Codes Refer- [How to retrieve the values from previous jsp page to result page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993935/how-to-retrieve-the-values-from-previous-jsp-page-to-result-page/19993995#19993995)

Comment: what exactly is your , binding this parameter to session totally works , so what exatly do you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%
String theAnswer1 = ...  
String userAnswer = (String)session.getAttribute("s1");
if (theAnswer.equals(userAnswer)) {
   out.println("Answer1 is correct - woohoo!");
} else {
   out.println("Question 1: Wrong answer - Correct answer is: " + theAnswer1)
}    
%>
```

Repeat the same pattern for answers 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: Note that above I did not provide code for how to get answer1, because I assume that information is known to you, as the developer of the quiz.

Comment: why scriplets? java has better things like JSTL and EL.

Comment: For consistency as the question used scriptlets.  This is just one answer.  If you feel JSTL/EL is a better alternative, feel free to post another answer.

Comment: I'm not good programmer but I think that using scriplets isn't good idea. Injecting business logic into view isn't good idea too? So may be it would be better to start you answer with advice to use JSTL?

Comment: @EJK: For example: theAnswer1 indicates India..what is userAnswer and theAnswer indicates ? I am getting error in second line

Comment: I used like this...   `String theAnswer1 = "New Delhi"; 
       String s1 = session.getAttribute("grp");
      if (s1.equals(theAnswer1))`  but showing error

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak - I agree that JSTL/EL is a better alternative, but given that the poster is obviously familiar with scriptlets, my objective is to provides something that works, so I am putting my answer in terms that are most likely to be understood.  If the poster wishes improve the solution by using a different approach, then s/he can do so.

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak - I fear that providing a JSTL/EL answer will just add confusion at this point.

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak: I am new to java. So, EJK is trying to solve this problem through scriplets. That is what I want..If you can, help me out of this using scriplets.

Comment: @DineshKumar - I think I know the problem.  I forgot to cast the "session.getAttribute" call to a String.  See my edits in about 30 seconds.

Comment: My edit is done: String userAnswer = (String)session.getAttribute("s1");

Comment: Please edit using my parameters and variables so that it will be easily understandable. You only know my previous codes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41241/discussion-between-ejk-and-dinesh-kumar)